# Problem with getting source code of page

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Java and in programming on android. Have a look at this code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
URI uri;
HttpResponse response = null;
String str = "dupa2";
try {
    uri = new URI("http://google.com");
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        response = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity enity = response.getEntity();
        str = enity.toString();
        str = "2";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        tv.setText("blad");
        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    tv.setText("blad");
    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
tv.setText(str);
setContentView(tv);
```

It doesn't work and i dont have idea why :/ str value is "dupa2" when it should be "2" (i added it because i didnt know whats going on) or "blad") WTF?

Must I add that try...catch statements?
Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: You need to look at your LogCat or whereever that Logger sends it's output. To see what the stacktrace is, that will tell you your error. I'll guess, you haven't got the manifest INTERNET permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you are getting an exception, add into your AndroidManifest.xml internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

post your stacktrace if this not solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've an exception thrown, so the `tv` text is set to `"blad"` and then again to `"dupa2"` (the 2nd line from the end).

Comment: gosh, you are right. It should be str = blad (in the catch blocks). Now I'm tracking down the line which threw error...